# Devise - user session still valid after sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Here is the scenario:
1. start the app
2. sign in as a user having remember_me = true
3. close the browser
4. restart the browser, user shown as signed in.
5. click on the sign out link.
6. Home or "/" page is rendered but user still shown as signed in.

I checked the heroku logs and the user is found and loaded when GET "/" is executed.

What is wrong here?
Otherwise the sign out works well if the browser is not closed and restarted.
The matter is consistent in dev and prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by upgrading to a new version for the devise gem. The authors provided the version 3.5.0 which solved the problem.